# Увеличение картинки и размещение её в центре

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

При нажатии на картинку, она должна появляться по центру страницы в полном размере (максимум `width: 1400px; height: 1000px`). Так же, желательно, чтобы весь остальной фон затемнялся (как показано на картинке). Как это можно реализовать на чистом css?

```css
.pictures {
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    -webkit-column-gap:   0px;
    -moz-column-count:    5;
    -moz-column-gap:      0px;
    column-count:         4;
    column-gap:           0px;
    
    width: 1200px;
}

.pictures img {
    display: flex;
    
    padding: 10px;
    
    width: 270px;
    height: auto; 
}
```

```html
<section class="pictures">
  <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/46871/pexels-photo-46871-large.jpeg">
  <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/60163/pexels-photo-60163-large.jpeg">
  <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/1539/vintage-technology-music-old-large.jpg">
  <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/36092/pexels-photo-large.jpg">
  <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/9014/car-orange-retro-large.jpg">
  <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/2017/vintage-music-closed-shop-large.jpg">
  <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/64687/pexels-photo-64687-large.jpeg">
  <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/474/black-and-white-car-vehicle-vintage-large.jpg">
  <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/5842/people-vintage-photo-memories-large.jpg">
  <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/2884/building-vintage-bike-monument-large.jpg">

</section>
```

[image: Как должна выглядеть картинка]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/cy3vg3ea/

```css
.pictures {
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  -moz-column-count: 4;
  column-count: 4;
  -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
  -moz-column-gap: 1em;
  column-gap: 1em;
  margin-bottom: -1em;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.full {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 8%;
  background: #CCC center no-repeat;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) center no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-origin: content-box;
}

.full:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section class="pictures">
  <a href="#pexels-photo-46871-large.jpeg"><img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/46871/pexels-photo-46871-large.jpeg"></a>
  <a id="pexels-photo-46871-large.jpeg" href="#" class="full" style="background-image:url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/46871/pexels-photo-46871-large.jpeg)"></a>
  <a href="#pexels-photo-60163-large.jpeg"><img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/60163/pexels-photo-60163-large.jpeg"></a>
  <a id="pexels-photo-60163-large.jpeg" href="#" class="full" style="background-image:url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/60163/pexels-photo-60163-large.jpeg)"></a>
  <a href="#vintage-technology-music-old-large.jpg"><img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/1539/vintage-technology-music-old-large.jpg"></a>
  <a id="vintage-technology-music-old-large.jpg" href="#" class="full" style="background-image:url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/1539/vintage-technology-music-old-large.jpg)"></a>
  <a href="#pexels-photo-large.jpg"><img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/36092/pexels-photo-large.jpg"></a>
  <a id="pexels-photo-large.jpg" href="#" class="full" style="background-image:url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/36092/pexels-photo-large.jpg)"></a>
  <a href="#car-orange-retro-large.jpg"><img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/9014/car-orange-retro-large.jpg"></a>
  <a id="car-orange-retro-large.jpg" href="#" class="full" style="background-image:url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/9014/car-orange-retro-large.jpg)"></a>
  <a href="#vintage-music-closed-shop-large.jpg"><img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/2017/vintage-music-closed-shop-large.jpg"></a>
  <a id="vintage-music-closed-shop-large.jpg" href="#" class="full" style="background-image:url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/2017/vintage-music-closed-shop-large.jpg)"></a>
  <a href="#pexels-photo-64687-large.jpeg"><img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/64687/pexels-photo-64687-large.jpeg"></a>
  <a id="pexels-photo-64687-large.jpeg" href="#" class="full" style="background-image:url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/64687/pexels-photo-64687-large.jpeg)"></a>
  <a href="#black-and-white-car-vehicle-vintage-large.jpg"><img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/474/black-and-white-car-vehicle-vintage-large.jpg"></a>
  <a id="black-and-white-car-vehicle-vintage-large.jpg" href="#" class="full" style="background-image:url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/474/black-and-white-car-vehicle-vintage-large.jpg)"></a>
  <a href="#people-vintage-photo-memories-large.jpg"><img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/5842/people-vintage-photo-memories-large.jpg"></a>
  <a id="people-vintage-photo-memories-large.jpg" href="#" class="full" style="background-image:url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/5842/people-vintage-photo-memories-large.jpg)"></a>
  <a href="#building-vintage-bike-monument-large.jpg"><img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/2884/building-vintage-bike-monument-large.jpg"></a>
  <a id="building-vintage-bike-monument-large.jpg" href="#" class="full" style="background-image:url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/2884/building-vintage-bike-monument-large.jpg)"></a>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3):

```css
.foto-previews > img {  
  padding: 10px;
  width: 270px;
  height: auto;
}

.fotobox {  
  display: none;
 position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0;
 z-index: 2000;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 text-align: center; 
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);   
}
.fotobox > img {  
 max-width: 90%;
 max-height: 80%; 
  border: 10px solid #fff;
  position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%;  
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.fotobox:target { 
 outline: none;
 display: block;   
}
```

```html
<section class="pictures">
 
  <a href="#foto1" class="foto-previews">
  <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/46871/pexels-photo-46871-large.jpeg">
</a>
<a href="#" class="fotobox" id="foto1">
  <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/46871/pexels-photo-46871-large.jpeg">
</a>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Без js нужно будет прослеживать высоту экрана media запросами, чтобы картинка была всегда в центре экрана, ну а пока что вот так:

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box; 
}

.thumb {
 max-width: 400px;
}

.big-picture, .big-picture:focus {
 display: block;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 text-align: center;
 opacity: 0;
 visibility: hidden;
 transition: 300ms;
}
.big-picture:target {
 opacity: 1;
 visibility: visible;
}
.big-picture:target img {
 transform: translateY(-50%)
}
.big-picture img {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin: auto;
 transform: translateY(-150%);
 max-width: 600px;
 width: 100%;
 border: 2px solid #fff; 
 transition: 500ms;
}
```

```html
<a href="#big-picture">
 <img class="thumb" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/46871/pexels-photo-46871-large.jpeg">
</a>

<a href="#" class="big-picture" id="big-picture">
 <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/46871/pexels-photo-46871-large.jpeg"/>
</a>
```

Comment: Не нужны тут медиа-запросы.

Comment: ну теоретически если наши картинки будут всегда одинакового размера, то можно медиа запросами ровнять  на маленьких экранах. Или есть другие варианты?

Comment: См. мой ответ. В сниппете не очень смотрится, в js-fiddle можно покрупнее сделать - там нормально.